# Difference between "distractors" and "foils"

Tags: experiment-design, psychometrics, psychology

What is the difference between "distractors" and "foils" in experimental design in psychology?

Comment: Aren't they the same ?

Comment: I'd think so too. However, if there are the same, why are they different words?

Comment: Maybe because they originate in different languages?

Comment: Fair enough. Surely we cannot have an experiment which utalised both "distractors" and "foils". I started thinking because my supervisor told me to correct what I called "distractors" into "foils", I still don't see why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know foils and distractors are the same.

For example, in constructing multiple choice questions, with only a single correct answer, the incorrect answers are distractors or foils (or misleads), and the correct answers are targets.

This terminology may vary depending on sub-disciplines. I would suggest you ask your supervisor for some clarity.